# Deployment failed at JBoss AS 5.1 (org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException)

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, jboss

This is the second time this error occurs. I'm not sure what should be because every time I do a dozen procedures over and over again (Clean, Add/Remove project, Build, etc...) and always in the same way, out of nowhere. Sometimes solve, but I know not what I do. This time not resolved and is the third day that I continue with this error preventing my work. Do not edit settings, just run and debug the project and this error happens.

So, come through advanced ask that the information can is causing this error to that (I hope not) happen again, I go directly to the focus error.

```
DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:

  Deployment "vfsfile:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/1_instancia/deploy/xyz-web.war/" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/C:/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/1_instancia/deploy/xyz-web.war/ deployment failed
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've tried deleting the `xyz-web.war` folder but made no effect, still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempts I found a "sequence" that eliminates this error. I say in quotes because there shouldn't be a sequence, but this way I could make the deploy the `.war` file not be corrupted. Come on, after the system displays the error message: remove the project of the server, `Project -> clean` -> click on the server -> `Add and remove` -> add the project and finally, in the project added to server right click in the mouse and select `Full Publish`

*After all this time, I realized that this error is because the `.war` file on the server is in error or inconsistency, either by changing the branch (versioning code) or by some change that was not well established in server, only the local file. The best you have to do is remove the server project, clean it, and build again (if not automatically build). After that, clean the server, worth checking if the application `.war` was actually deleted from the deployment folder, if not, you need to delete manually. Done all the cleaning in the application and server, add the application to the server, publish it altogether and try to reconnect the server.*

Answer (score 0):

Kindly follow the below steps:

Step 1:
Stop the server and remove all the .temp files from deploy

Step 2:
Remove data,log,work,tmp folder from your directory(jboss\server\default)

Step 3:
Remove your current working war folder "xyz.war" from the deploy folder
and redeploy

Then start the server.This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the running Server
Clean the project(*Project->Clean->Clean Project Select Below->[Select Project]->Ok*) & Clean the server(If you already configure the server just *right click* and click *Clean*)
Start the server and access the Url.